# error hermes startHeadlessTask react native 0.63 when listen react native firebase messaging in quite state

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I want to ask, i got an error when i receive push notification data only when apps state is quite / kill apps.

```
[Mon Nov 23 2020 18:09:48.345]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling startHeadlessTask), js engine: hermes
```

this error appear when i run in android

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to implement `setBackgroundMessageHandler` at the level where you're registering the app. I passed an empty `Promise.resolve` since I'm not performing any tasks in the background. It appears that when a notification is triggered whilst the app is not running (completely quit) it attempts to run a headless task so if a handler is not set it throws.

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(() => Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Could you please add the import for `messaging`? I don't know where I should be importing it from